# javascript - set select option value to null

Tags: javascript

I have to disable all the `select` menus in a `div` and also set their value to `null`.

I am using the following code to disable the select menus:

```
  var div_contents =document.getElementById("div1");
  var elements = div_contents.getElementsByTagName("select");
  for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].disabled = true;
  }
```

However, I am not able to set the value of the select tag to `null`.

Also I don't have the `null` option inside the `select` tag:

```
<select id="test1" name="test1">
    <option value="a">aa</option>
    <option value="b">bb</option>
    <option value="c">cc</option>
</select>
```

How can I set the value of a `select` list to `null`, given that I don't have the `null` option?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Do you want to remove all of the options completely?

Comment: your code is right, you are just disabling the boxed to set the value null use **elements[i].value = ''**

Comment: Using 'elements[i].selectedIndex = -1;' seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to show no selection, you should set its `selectedIndex` to `-1`.

```
elements[i].selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting the element's `value` property:

```
elements[i].value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working. I have tested it.

```
elements[i].value = ' ';

elements[i].trigger('change');
```